# The code to add_submenu_page, where do I put it?

Tags: wordpress, menu, admin

I know the code I have to use from the [Wordpress reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page#Source_File), but noone gives any indication as to where to place said code.

Where would I place:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_appearance_menu');
function add_appearance_menu(){
     add_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'My Theme Settings', 'My Theme Settings', 1, 'my-theme-settings', $function);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd put it into `functions.php`, in your theme directory, most likely.

Comment: Thanks, I'm only just starting out and don't full understand how they've set it out yet.